# Cannot install Grails plugin with Eclipse (Grails 2.3.1)

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.3

i have `Grails 2.3.1`.

when i try to install new plugins , i have the following console message :

```
Since Grails 2.3, it is no longer possible to install plugins using the install-plugin command.
Plugins must be declared in the grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy file.
Example:
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
   ...
   plugins {
      compile ":console:1.2"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Grails 2.3, it is no longer possible to install plugins using the `install-plugin` command.

Plugins must be declared in the `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` file.

Instead of using `install-plugin` (or an IDE feature like you're using that runs `install-plugin` for you), add a dependency in the `plugins` section in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
plugins {
   compile ":console:1.2"
}
```

`install-plugin` adds entries in `application.properties` but that approach isn't configurable enough, so we deprecated `install-plugin` in 2.2 and removed it in 2.3. As you can see, when you run the script, it does nothing but does give you the code that you need to add yourself.